# Writing an Application for WiFi Direct on C#

Tags: c#, android, api, wifi, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm developing an Android App for ICS using WiFi Direct new API.

I'm looking to connect to my pc and send some data. Is this is the corect API to use?
Does anyone has a quick sample of using it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.ipeerfinderstatics.allowwifidirect

By yhe way- Does any one understand if it's something only for Metro Style Apps, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can establish the connection between your PC and phone. On the other hand, it works fine with devices that have OS 4.0.1 (Although there are some conflicts with higher versions)

Take a look at these links anyway.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/wifip2p.html

Comment: Thanks,
but I wanted to connect my Android 4 device to my PC with W.D.
That was the whole catch...

Comment: Ow ok. I guess I misread your question. My fault. But anyway, you can still find a way to connect your device to your PC over wifi direct. In this case, you might need to develop a small console application for your PC where you can manipulate your wificonfig. However, I don't have any extra material to provide other than the links above. Sorry about that.